# Microservice communication

Tags: microservices

I'm quite new to microservices and I'm studying what is the best approach when it comes to microservice inter communication and fallback scenarios.

For example:

if service **A** is calling service **B** to get a particular data.

Case:

1. What if service **B** is not available? How should it reflect on the Front end? is the best solution be just prompt a error that the service is unavailable?
2. What about the data being passed on? should I assume the it is already lost?

Comment: is the nature of the service such that periods of unavailability are expected?

Comment: Case 1 is entirely subjective. You may want to only display an error when actively using the service. There may be heartbeat you can monitor. You may want to provide some default behaviour. There are many possibilities...

Comment: This kind of architecture is very hard to take forward. Even for very experienced devs. How to deal with eventual consistency depends entirely on the business and very little on the technique to implement it. There's no easy answers and the few you will get are going to be pure theory and none practical. The best you can do is to read about Eventual Consistency and put your hands on the job. This is a path with no shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no general answer for this. When you are using (micro-)services, you are building a *distributed system*. Distributed systems are massively more complex than a monolithic system exactly because we have to think about such things like partial failures and maintaining consistency – it's great that you immediately spotted these problems!

Therefore, microservices are not always a good choice, particularly not if you can easily solve your problems without them. They tend to become attractive when you are having other really big problems (like organizational requirements, or having to scale horizontally for performance), so that the potential drawbacks of microservices look acceptable *in comparison*.

There are a few general strategies and recommendations that can help, depending on your exact requirements:

- Each instance of the service should be **stateless**. Any data must be stored externally of the service. This allows us to:
- Run **multiple instances** of a service and load-balance between them. This allows us to perform horizontal scaling on a per-service granularity, and maintains availability if one instance fails.
- Define clear **transactions**. A transactional operation has no effect until it is complete. This ensures that there are no partially-done operations. If a transaction is aborted, it can be retried. Because each service instance should be stateless this usually requires support of a DB, but please note that NoSQL DBs differ drastically in what kinds of transactions they support.
- Not all processes can be modeled as a single transaction, especially when you have to interact with external services. Here, splitting the process into multiple **transactional steps** and keeping track of the state of the process may be a solution.
- Consider whether processes have to be **synchronous** (every request gets a response) or can be **asynchronous** (events/jobs/messages are added to a queue and processed later). Asynchronous operations allow for much more flexibility. Then, adding the job to the queue is a transactional operation which promises that the job will be processed “soon”, at some point in the future. A job is removed from the queue after it was successfully processed. But the actual processing is not part of the transaction. This allows you to retry the job in the background, or hold it until another service is available again.
- Make a distinctions between **errors** within the problem domain and **failures** of your system. System failures are likely temporary and can be solved by retrying the same request later. In HTTP, this is roughly the difference between 400 and 500 response codes. In single-page web applications, a common “failure” is that the client simply has no network connection. Consider whether updates can be queued for later. To check whether the service is available again, prefer a strategy like exponential backoff to avoid DDOSing yourself.
- Consider various **consistency strategies** for concurrently updating data. One simple approach is last one wins. However, this might overwrite a change that has happened in the meantime.

  A more sophisticated approach is test-and-set / **optimistic locking**: An update contains both the old data and the new data. The old data might simply be an ID or hash instead of the full data. Within the protection of a transaction, the new data is only written if the relevant old data is in the expected state, otherwise an error is returned. In SQL this is as simple as an `UPDATE ... WHERE ...` statement that verifies the old state. An error will usually require a (human) user to reconcile the new state with the intended change and resubmit the change.

  The HTTP protocol has built-in support for optimistic locking via ETags + the `If-Match` header, and could respond with a 409 Conflict or 412 Precondition Failed status if a POST or PUT could not be applied.

  Having a clear strategy to ensure consistency is important if a request is retried that was already handled. E.g. consider a service that has processed a transaction successfully but crashes before the success response can be sent.

Answer (score 0):

> What if service B is not available? How should it reflect on the Front end?

I'm not sure what you mean by 'front end'? Is that service A?
At any rate, if service A calls service B, and service B fails, there are two classes of cases. If the error was 4xx, then you should service A should fail the request (that triggered it calling service B) - probably with a 5xx error because there is likely a bug with service A.

If service B returned a 5xx error (indicating a possibly temporary) failure in its execution - you should generally have the call service A is handling (which triggers the call to service B) fail with a the same 500 error from upstream (indicating if the problem is temporary or more permanent to the caller).

If you meant for serviceA to be "the front end" - then the question is is answered. If you meant in general how to display on a ui that you are getting errors from backend services, this depends on the nature of the service requests (calls to service A from the frontend / gui) - but usually some sort of dialog box indicating failure is the least bad choice. This is really much more complicated, but as I'm not sure its really what you are asking, I'll skip detail there.

> What about the data being passed on? should I assume the it is already lost?

If you call any service and get back a 4xx or 5xx error, you should assume your request has not been processed. So the short answer is - yes - your data is lost.

The slightly longer answer, is that its sometimes good architectural choice to have the first 'service' handling requests from the GUI - to be some sort message queuing service (e.g. Apache Kafka), which can handle retries with the upstream processing services fail.

Answer (score 0):

> What if service B is not available?

By definition, micro service needs to be **very** independent from another micro services. So independent that the other micro services doesn't care what is happening with another micro services. But, eventually, it can have some dependency, but this is not the best scenario for a micro service.

Said that, you can have two kind of communications with another micro service: **Asynchronous** and **Synchronous**.

The **Synchronous** communication between services is called **RPC** (*Remote Procedure Call*). This can be done using a simple HTTP request for the another system or even using some Queue system (RabbitMQ, Kafka, etc). As a RPC example, the service A calls service B and wait for B answer. If B not answer, the service A needs to know what he will do. He can:

- **Ignore**. The information from B is not so important.
- **Try again later**. You can get the information later or never. You can inform the user about that if is necessary and use some strategy to try again later to get the information from B.
- **Throw an error**. The service A can't continue without the service B information.

With **Asynchronous** communication your application will be prepared to survive without that information from service B and without knowing what is happening with B. The communication concept use *events*, where each service is listening for the events from another micro services that he have interest and react to them when some message arrives (saving the info in his own database, sending an e-mail, logging the event, etc).

This most popular way to implement this *events* on micro services is using some Messaging system, like RabbitMQ or Kafka. This applications use the Queue concept and messages, where the service can connect to this Queues and read the messages from the Queue.

> How should it reflect on the Front end? Is the best solution be just prompt a error that the service is unavailable?

Depends. If the information is vital for A, this is necessary. But maybe your service can continue without the information from B, but you need to have some path on your service to try to get that information again.

> What about the data being passed on? should I assume the it is already lost?

The data cannot be simply "lost". If you are using the RPC communication, you can try again later to send the information from B. It's expected that you can reproduce the same request and try again later.

Using *Asynchronous* communication, the information will be in the Queues expecting to some service consume them.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** These are largely just business decision. Fulfilling a digital request is a lot like fulfilling a phone call — everything just happens faster. I'd suggest you start by following your in-person or on-phone business/customer service rules. Optimize where possible.

---

Reframe the question in terms of *an employee in on the phone with a customer at a "paper-only" company*. Near the end of the call, the customer has given the employee everything they need to potentially fulfill an order:

> Hey, I need 100 Widgets. My account number is 1234. Ship to the address on file. Use the card on file. It's been authorized by Bill Murray, whose PIN is 5678. And no, I would not like to opt into marketing emails ...

... and now, the employee needs to respond definitively to the request. They need to perform some validation steps and fulfillment paperwork. Perhaps the business wants them to:

1. Call account management / Run to the file room ...

   1. Retrieve the file
   2. Verify the account number
   3. Ensure the account *has* a shipping address
   4. Ensure the account has billing information
   5. Verify Bill Murray's PIN
2. Call the shipment company

   1. Verify the address
3. Call the warehouse

   1. Verify at least 100 Widget are available
   2. Put 100 Widgets on hold
4. Prepare a formal order record

   1. Call the bank and verify funds / Initiate a transaction
   2. Add the transaction number to the paperwork
5. Head to the mail room

   1. Copy the paperwork
   2. Print a shipping label
   3. Put in envelope with shipping label
   4. Send to warehouse
6. Tell the customer the order is in

Or something like that. But uhh ...

- What if file cabinet door is jammed?
- What if someone else never returned the file?
- What if the shipment company isn't available to verify the address?
- What if the warehouse line is busy?
- What if the copier is in use?
- What if the shipping label machine is broken?
- **Does the customer wait on the phone while you do all this??!!**
- ***WHAT IF THE BUILDING CATCHES FIRE!!??!!??***

...

So, maybe your leadership team decides some of these things are optional, depending on the status of the account. Maybe some things are worth repeated attempts (is it OK to just *wait* for the copier or *redial the warehouse after 30 seconds?*). Or maybe some of them don't ultimately add value at all (*verify the address?!*). Or, you decide some of them can be done after the call — and you can call the customer back if there are problems (submitting to warehouse?). ... And, maybe some of them are just show-stoppers altogether.

Like, if the building catches fire, it's probably appropriate to tell the customer to just call back later. And, perhaps you don't have a good solution for back-filling orders, so, if you can't confirm and hold inventory, the customer has to try again in *N days.*

Now, given the things that you and your business folks have decided about how this phone call should proceed when various troubles and uncertainties arise, you *start* by just scaling the rules down form the 1 to 3 minutes they expect to wait on the phone to the 1 to 3 seconds they'll wait for a page load.

Then, step up or step down your digital service level based on the relative speed and reliability of your digital dependencies over their non-digital counterparts.

You might find that service outages at your load level are so rare that ... you don't even need a robust plan. Just tell the customer to "call back" any time something goes wrong. It's up to you and/or your leadership.

They're just business rules, informed by technical limitations. Technical limitations that, honestly, often mirror human interactions quite well — just a hell of a lot faster.